# Are case activity revisions no longer working?

Tags: civicase, activities

Not sure when this changed. I'm using the master branch. There's a couple related things:

1. The default for "logging" on the Misc admin screen is off, but so is the default for "Enable Embedded Activity Revisions" on the CiviCase settings admin screen. So by default nothing is logged anymore.
2. Even if I turn on the setting on the civicase settings screen, it seems that there's then two sub-issues:

   (a) a quick look at the code used by the activity form suggests it doesn't use this setting, and

   (b) it looks like it should be making revisions anyway, but doesn't.

I can reproduce on dmaster.demo.

Anybody know when this changed and/or is it an intended change?

**EDIT**: This line 453 in postProcess is *part* of the problem, because it overwrites part of the passed in $params, but there's more going on somewhere too. Removing the line or reversing the arguments causes different problems.

`$params = array_merge($oldActivity, $params);`

Comment: Is this related? https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/commit/58e9d36432b501ba6ff039d545186f4d138a5f30

Comment: Thanks but no - that just sets the setting on upgrade, and even if you change it there's no revisions created. The API does seem to honor it, but not the actual activity edit form. At some point I'll run a debugger on it, but was just wondering if anyone knew if this was on purpose and when, or if it's a bug introduced somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you answered your own question...  and wrote a whole extension to migrate sites off activity revisions! https://civicrm.org/extensions/caseactivityrevisionmigrator